# How to explicitly validate a knockoutJs observable

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using KnoockoutJS and the validation plugin from here, https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation.

By default, validation messages only appear after a field has been modified. The problem is that when the user  clicks "Save", I need to validate the bound observable regardless of whether the user has modified the field or not.

I can't seem to find a .Validate()on an obervable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `ko.validation.validateObservable` might be what you're looking for... I didn't test it, but that looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ko.validatedObservable($data)().isValid()` to get whether the viewmodel is false or not.

If there is somebody who knows a better way, please leave a comment :)